# How to add Nested arrays to my model class

Tags: json, swift3, swifty-json

I get the below response from the API. I need to model the response into classes in swift 3.
The Api Response in JSON is as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "CategoryName": "אהבה",
      "CategoryID": "61",
      "CategoryDate": "2016-08-26 02:11:43",
      "CategoryImage": "love.png",
      "SubCategoryArray": [
        {
          "SubCategoryName": "אהבה",
          "SubCategoryRefID": "61",
          "SubCategoryID": "115",
          "SubCategoryDate": "2016-08-29 09:25:56",
          "TextArray": [
            {
              "TextID": "103",
              "Text": "<p dir=\"rtl\"><span style=\"font-size:48px\"><strong>אוהב</strong> אותך כל כך</span></p>\r\n"
            },
```

How can I model the subCategory and TextArray subclasses.

I am using SwiftyJSON to populate my model class

My model classes are as shown below;

```
class Menu
{
    var CategoryName: String?
    var CategoryID: String?
    var CategoryDate: String?
    var CategoryImage: String?
    var SubCategoryArray: [SubCategoryArray]?

    init(CategoryName: String?, CategoryID: String?, CategoryDate: String?, CategoryImage: String?, SubCategoryArray: [SubCategoryArray]?) {
        self.CategoryName = CategoryName
        self.CategoryID = CategoryID
        self.CategoryDate = CategoryDate
        self.CategoryImage = CategoryImage
        self.SubCategoryArray = SubCategoryArray
    }
}


class SubCategoryArray
{
    var SubCategoryName: String?
    var SubCategoryRefID: String?
    var SubCategoryID: String?
    var SubCategoryDate: String?
    var TextArray : [TextArray]?
    init(SubCategoryName: String?, SubCategoryRefID: String?, SubCategoryID: String?, SubCategoryDate: String?, TextArray: [TextArray]?) {
        self.SubCategoryName = SubCategoryName
        self.SubCategoryRefID = SubCategoryRefID
        self.SubCategoryID = SubCategoryID
        self.SubCategoryDate = SubCategoryDate
        self.TextArray = TextArray
    }
}


class TextArray
{
    var TextID: String?
    var Text: String?

    init (TextID:String? , Text: String? )
    {
        self.TextID = TextID
        self.Text = Text
    }
}
```

I am storing it as

```
if let json = try? JSON(result){
var menus = [Menu]()                    
for (_, content) in json["data"] {
let menu = Menu(CategoryName: (content["CategoryName"].string),
 CategoryID: content["CategoryID"].string,
 CategoryDate: content["CategoryDate"].string,
 CategoryImage: content["CategoryImage"],
 SubCategoryArray: content["SubCategoryArray"].string)
 menus.append(menu)
 }
```

The only issue is how to do it for the `SubCategory` class and `TextArray` class.

Comment: why not use ObjectMapper instead of swiftyjson ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, i would recommend to lowercase the variable names.

Also, i would rename `TextArray` class to `Text`, and `SubCategoryArray` class to `SubCategory`, because they are not arrays, and the name can be very misleading.

At last, lets initialise `subCategoryArray` and `textArray`  as an empty array of `SubCategory` and `Text`, instead of being optional. This way, whenever you use it in the future, you do not have to run `nil` check on it, just check if `isEmpty`.

What  you need to do, is just to iterate on the incoming object, and create your arrays. Please, take a look on the code below.

```
class Menu {
    var categoryName: String?
    var categoryID: String?
    var categoryDate: String?
    var categoryImage: String?
    var subCategoryArray = [SubCategory]()

    init(categoryName: String?, categoryID: String?, categoryDate: String?, categoryImage: String?, subCategoryArray: [Any]?) {
        self.categoryName = categoryName
        self.categoryID = categoryID
        self.categoryDate = categoryDate
        self.categoryImage = categoryImage

        // lets check if SubCategoryArray is not nil
        if let subCategoryArray = subCategoryArray as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            // lets iterate on the raw data
            subCategoryArray.forEach({ (subCategoryCandidate) in
                // Create category
                let subcategory = SubCategory(subCategoryName: subCategoryCandidate["SubCategoryName"] as? String, 
                    subCategoryRefID: subCategoryCandidate["SubCategoryRefID"] as? String, 
                    subCategoryID: subCategoryCandidate["SubCategoryID"] as? String,
                    subCategoryDate: subCategoryCandidate["SubCategoryDate"] as? String, 
                    textArray: subCategoryCandidate["TextArray"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])
                // Append to our array
                self.subCategoryArray.append(subcategory)
            })
        }
    }
}

// lets rename this class only to SubCategory, because this is not an array at all
class SubCategory {
    var subCategoryName: String?
    var subCategoryRefID: String?
    var subCategoryID: String?
    var subCategoryDate: String?
    var textArray = [Text]()
    init(subCategoryName: String?, subCategoryRefID: String?, subCategoryID: String?, subCategoryDate: String?, textArray: [[String: AnyObject]]?) {
        self.subCategoryName = subCategoryName
        self.subCategoryRefID = subCategoryRefID
        self.subCategoryID = subCategoryID
        self.subCategoryDate = subCategoryDate

        if let textArray = textArray {
            textArray.forEach({ (textArrayCandidate) in
                let text = Text(textID: textArrayCandidate["TextID"] as? String, text: textArrayCandidate["Text"] as? String)
                self.textArray.append(text)
            })
        }
    }
}

// Rename this to Text, because this is also not an array
class Text {
    var textID: String?
    var text: String?

    init(textID:String? , text: String? ) {
        self.textID = textID
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
let url = URL(string: "YOUR-URL")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let data = data, let json = try? JSON(data) {

        var menus = [Menu]()                    
        for (_, content) in json["data"] {
            let menu = Menu(categoryName: (content["CategoryName"].string),
                            categoryID: content["CategoryID"].string,
                            categoryDate: content["CategoryDate"].string,
                            categoryImage: content["CategoryImage"].string,
                            subCategoryArray: content["SubCategoryArray"].arrayObject)
            menus.append(menu)
        }

        print(menus) // prints 6 items for me
    }
});
task.resume()
```

}

Comment: by writting a unit test maybe? or what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the absurd question Well I tied using breaks and this part of the code jumps over  if let subCategoryArray = subCategoryArray {
            // lets iterate on the raw data
            subCategoryArray.forEach({ (subCategoryCandidate) in and the value stored is nil

Comment: subCategoryArray: content["SubCategoryArray"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]) .      I get a warning here that cast from JSON to unrelated type [[String:AnyObject]] always fail

Comment: i will take a look in a minute

Comment: it has to be something to do with you using SwiftyJSON. you need to get there an array of dictionaries. it should be something like content["SubCategoryArray"].array. I am looking currently at the SwiftyJSON documentation, will get back with the exact solution.

Comment: BTW I am open to dump off Swifty JSON just in case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133434/discussion-between-dirtydanee-and-md-ibrahim-hassan).